# Updating LibreOffice on Linux clients

Tags: linux-mint, libreoffice

We currently have Linux Mint installed on a number of devices and would like to upgrade the version of LibreOffice installed i.e. 3.4.4 to the latest version of 3.5.2 however upon running the command `apt-get update && apt-get -s install libreoffice` it returns the version 3.4.4.

Now having read a number of posts e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/96161/how-to-update-libreoffice-to-the-latest-version, it is suggested that I wait until the next version of Ubuntu released which I don't.

I am also aware that I can run the command `apt-add-repository` to add a Personal Package Archive (PPA) however when I run the command `apt-add-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa` I am returned the message `Most of the packages in this ppa have only experienced minor testing -- in fact it is the place to enable a wider audience to test packages before they are published into the distro proper......`

I also downloaded a tar gzip package of LibreOffice from the official website however having gone through the readme, it is recommend that I use the package manager that comes with Debian or Ubuntu derivatives.

My question is that if I want to install the latest version of LibreOffice, what is the best way to do it. If the suggest is to go down the route of using Personal Package Archive (PPA), would it be recommended to delete the list of repositories after the latest version of LibreOffice has been installed and if so why aside from the fact that unstable versions of the package may be installed e.g. security issues, etc?

Comment: Why don't you attempt to install the `.deb` that libreoffice.org provides such as [x86](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/?type=deb-x86&lang=en-US&version=3.5.2) or [x86_64](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/?type=deb-x86_64&lang=en-US&version=3.5.2)?

Comment: @Dan D. - I did looking at installing the `.deb` package that LibreOffice provides however as noted the readme instructions note the following `As a general rule, you are recommended to install LibreOffice via the installation methods recommended by your particular Linux distribution (such as the Ubuntu Software Center, in the case of Ubuntu Linux). This is because it is usually the simplest way to obtain an installation that is optimally integrated into your system. `

Comment: Yes, if they had the version of the package you want, but it would still be better to use the `.deb` provided by them than to attempt to install the `.tar.gz` they provide.

Comment: @Dan D - Righto. Do I need to uninstall the previous version using the command `apt-get autoremove libreoffice` or `apt-get remove --purge libreoffice or is there no need to uninstall the previous version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already found out from the wiki, it's recommended to wait for an update from you distribution. Most of the time they choose to support (i.e. providing security fixes) an older version than the current one. They then  update to a major new version on a new release (of their distribution).

LibO releases a stable release every half-year and then refines it until it's "enterprise stable". See their [release policy](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/release-policy/) for details.

So you basically have three options:

1. Wait for the official update and keep using the 'old' version.
2. Install the PPA channel. Then you'll get the latest LibO version and it automatically updates on new releases.
3. Install the .deb or .tar.gz and update manually

If you can take the occasional bug (not too serious ones, honestly) but want/need to live on the cutting-edge, go for the PPA.

If you need enterprise stable, wait for the next version of your distribution.

If you want to update to a specific version and plan to use that, install the .deb.